# Dynamic condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

Can someone help me to solved my issue for build dynamic condition in php...

i have an array

```
$condition = array('FADR1','FADR2','FADR3','SADR1','SADR2','SADR3');
```

i have tried this code but the result not like i want

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($condition) ; $i++) {
       if($keydt == $condition[$i]){
              $separator = '';
       }else{
              $separator = '|';
       }
}
```

i want to make array become like this inside loop

```
if($keydt == 'FADR1' or $keydt == 'FADR2' or $keydt == 'FADR3' or $keydt == 'SADR1' or $keydt == 'SADR2' or $keydt == 'SADR3'){
     $separator = '';
}else{
     $separator = '|';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in_array()` to check if a value exists inside an array.

```
if (in_array($keydt, $condition)) {
    $separator = '';
} else {
    $separator = '|';
}
```

- [PHP.net on `in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: https://eval.in/89008 - never do this! always use strict mode for in_array - for more examples of crazy shit in_array does in non-strict mode, see https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/1v7ek6/in_which_in_array_does_crazy_stuff/

Answer (score 1):

you could try using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function, example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($condition) ; $i++) {
    if (in_array($condition[$i], array('FADR1', 'FADR2', 'FADR3', 'SADR1', 'SADR2', 'SADR3'), true)) {
        $separator = '';
    } else {
        $separator = '|';
    }
}
```

another example using foreach...

```
foreach ($condition as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, array('FADR1', 'FADR2', 'FADR3', 'SADR1', 'SADR2', 'SADR3'), true)) {
        $separator = '';
    } else {
        $separator = '|';
    }
}
```

I hope that help you.

Regards.

Comment: https://eval.in/89008 - never do this! always use strict mode for in_array - for more examples of crazy shit in_array does in non-strict mode, see https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/1v7ek6/in_which_in_array_does_crazy_stuff/